# XPath doesn't return < symbol

Tags: php, xpath

I'm using the Symfony Crawler component which use XPath itself.
I have a HTML of a nutritional table

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td> Carbohydrate </td>
    <td> 10g </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Fat </td>
    <td> < 0,1 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is what I tried

```
$fatCell = $browser->filterXPath('//td[contains(text(), "Fat")]');
```

```
$fatCell->outerHtml() will return  
<td>\n
Fat\n
</td>

$fatCell->nextAll()->outerHtml() will return
<td>\n
\n
</td>
```

And I try to get the information with XPath query, but when I try to access to fat informations, it's empty, it seems that the character `<` is misunderstood by XPath,
can I do something for this ?

Comment: A literal `<` in the document like that breaks the document, and XML parsers tend to behave poorly with malformed documents. It needs to be escaped as `&lt;`.

Comment: I would suggest using &#60; instead of < in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Carbohydrate</td>
<td>10g</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Fat</td>
<td>&#60; 0,1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I actually forgot to say that the HTML come from a website so I cannot change it, but I use `str_replace()` with @Sammitch 's solution so it works well ! Thank you guys

Comment: Glad you fixed it!